# How long does Canon 7D mk II last in standby?

Tags: canon-7d, battery-drain

I've heard that **Canon 7D mark II** eats battery quickly even with GPS off. Is it just a bug of some of the devices or a typical behaviour?

How long does it last on a single (original) battery **idle/turned-off with/without GPS**?

The most important for me is an info about how long does it last to be **turned-off without GPS**

I typically travel with the camera couple of weeks without electricity and I need to rely just on the batteries I'll bring with me. 
I know the shooting style makes a difference (and some clue comes from the camera spec) so I ask just for the idle time.

Comment: You should specify the type of battery you use, as that may have a large influence on how long the camera is able to maintain stand-by mode.

Comment: I've updated I am interested in original (made by Canon) battery performance.

Comment: I can comment about the Canon 6D, which has GPS too. When GPS is disabled and the camera is left on standby, the battery will easily last 3 weeks or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the Canon 7D Mk II and I have seen it last upwards of a month if not longer on standby without the GPS on. I don't know what the official length of time is from Canon, but I find it barely uses any battery when in stand by from my experience.

Even the one weekend I left the GPS on, as long as the GPS is locked in, its not to hard on the battery. If the GPS is having issues with locking in, it will kill the battery must faster then normal.

Now I recommend that you have a 2nd battery fully charged in your bag just in case if the one in the camera dies and you are not in a place to charge it again.